# Pizzas purchased program Java *FIXED*

Tags: java

Entry level java program that won't compile. Any help at all would be amazing! I really just need a quick review of my basic level code. I get errors for ints, booleans, and doubles. I've tried to rearrange them in multiple ways and i just can not get it to work. Also my Cheesy crust calculation to add it the total. Again super novice but would really enjoy the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class programmingassignment1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

      int pizzaLength;
      int pizzaWidth;
      int pizzaShape;
      double pizzaDiamiter;
      double pizzaToppingPrice = 0.025;
      int numberOfPizzaToppings;
      double pizzaSauceAndCheese = 0.036;
      double pizzaDoughPrice = 0.019;
      char doughType;
      String dough;
      int numberOfPizzas;
      double pizzasBeforeTax;
      int cheesyCrustInput;
      int deliveryWantedInput;
      int deliveryCharge;
      double doughVolume;
      double area;
      double crustCost;
      int basePrice;
      int costOfPizzaWithTax;


      //Shape of pizza
      System.out.println("What shape of pizza requested?");
      System.out.println("Enter (1) for Rectange or (2) Round?");
      pizzaShape = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if(pizzaShape == 1){
               System.out.println("What Length?");
               pizzaLength = keyboard.nextInt();
               System.out.println("What Width?");
               pizzaWidth = keyboard.nextInt();
               area = pizzaLength * pizzaWidth;
               }
      else if(pizzaShape == 2){
               System.out.println("What is the Diamiter?");
               pizzaDiamiter = keyboard.nextInt();
               area = Math.PI * (pizzaDiamiter / 2);
               }

      //Volume
      System.out.print("What type of dough do you want? (1)Classic Hand-Tossed, (2)Thin and Crispy, (3)Texas Toast, or (4)Pan. (enter 1,2,3, or 4.");
      doughType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if (doughType == 1) {
          dough = "Classic Hand-Tossed";
          doughVolume = area * .25;
          } 
      else if (doughType == 2) {
          dough = "Thin and Crispy";
          doughVolume = area * .1;
          } 
      else if (doughType == 3) {
          dough = "Texas Toast";
          doughVolume = area * .9;
          }
      else if (doughType == 4) {
          dough = "Pan";
          doughVolume = area * .5;
          }  

      //Cheesey crust
      if(doughType == 2){
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("Would you like cheesy crust? (1) for yes (2) for no");
          cheesyCrustInput = keyboard.nextInt();
               if(cheesyCrustInput == 1){
               crustCost = area * .02;
               String Crust = "";
               }
               else{
               String Crust = "NO";
               }
      }

      //Toppings
      System.out.print("Enter the number of toppings:");
      numberOfPizzaToppings = keyboard.nextInt();
      if(numberOfPizzaToppings == 0){
         String toppings = "no";
         }
      else{
         int toppings = numberOfPizzaToppings;
         }

      //Base price
      basePrice = area (pizzaSauceAndCheese + (pizzaToppingPrice * numberOfPizzaToppings) + (pizzaDoughPrice * doughVolume));

      //how many pizzas
       System.out.print("Enter the number of pizzas being ordered:");
       numberOfPizzas = keyboard.nextInt();
       pizzasBeforeTax = basePrice * numberOfPizzas;

      //tax
      costOfPizzaWithTax = pizzasBeforeTax ( 1 + 0.07);

      //delivery fee
      System.out.print("Would you like delivery? (1) for yes, (2) for no.");
      deliveryWantedInput = keyboard.nextInt();
      if(deliveryWantedInput == 1){
         String deliveryOutput = numberOfPizzas + "deliverd";
         if(costOfPizzaWithTax < 10){
         deliveryCharge = 3;
         }
         if( 10 < costOfPizzaWithTax && costOfPizzaWithTax < 20 ){
         deliveryCharge = 2;
         }
         if(20 < costOfPizzaWithTax && costOfPizzaWithTax < 30){
         deliveryCharge = 1;
         }
         if(costOfPizzaWithTax > 30){
         deliveryCharge = 0;
         }
      }
      else{
      String deliveryOutput = "no delivery";
      }

      //display total
      total = costOfPizzaWithTax + deliveryCharge;
      System.out.println("Total Due: $" + df.format(total));
      if(pizzaShape = 1){
      System.out.print("User requested: Rectangular, " + pizzaWidth + "X" + pizzaLength + ", " + dough + toppings + "topping(s)" 
                      + Crust + "cheesy crust," + deliveryOutput + " - Program Output:");
      System.out.println("Details for - Rectangular Pizza (" + pizzaWidth + "\" X " + pizzaLength + "\"):");
      System.out.println( "Area:  " + area );
      System.out.println( "Volume:" + doughVolume);
      System.out.println( "Base price:   $" + basePrice);
      System.out.println( "With Cheesy:  $");
      System.out.println( "Multi Total:  $" + pizzasBeforeTax);
      System.out.println( "With Tax:     $" + costOfPizzaWithTax);
      System.out.println( "And Delivery: $" + total);

      }
      else{
      System.out.print("User requested: Circular, " + pizzaDiamiter + "\", " + dough + toppings + "topping(s)" 
                      + Crust + "cheesy crust," + deliveryOutput + " - Program Output:");
      System.out.println( "Area:  " + area );
      System.out.println( "Volume:" + doughVolume);
      System.out.println( "Base price:   $" + basePrice);
      System.out.println( "With Cheesy:  $");
      System.out.println( "Multi Total:  $" + pizzasBeforeTax);
      System.out.println( "With Tax:     $" + costOfPizzaWithTax);
      System.out.println( "And Delivery: $" + total);
      }                   
   }
}
```

---

Fixed content follows below!

import java.util.Scanner;

public class programmingassignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double PIZZA_TOPPING_PRICE = 0.025;
  final double PIZZA_SAUCE_AND_CHEESE = 0.036;
    final double PIZZA_DOUGH_PRICE = 0.019;
  double numberOfPizzaToppings;
  double crustCost;
    double basePrice;
  double radiusOfPizza;
    double sizeOfPizzaCrust;
  double pizzasBeforeTax;
  double pizzaLength = 1;
    double pizzaWidth = 1;
    double pizzaShape = 1;
    double pizzaDiamiter = 0;
    double doughType = 1;
    double numberOfPizzas = 0;
    double cheesyCrustInput = 0;
    double deliveryWantedInput = 0;
    double deliveryCharge = 0;
    double doughVolume = 1;
    double area = 1;
    double costOfPizzaWithTax = 1;
    double total = 1;
    double toppings = 1;
  String dough = "";
  String crust = "";
    String deliveryOutput;
  String cheesyOutput = "";

    // Shape of pizza
    System.out.println("What shape of pizza requested?");
    System.out.println("Enter (1) for Rectangle or (2) Round:");
    pizzaShape = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (pizzaShape == 1) {
        System.out.println("What Length?");
        pizzaLength = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What Width?");
        pizzaWidth = keyboard.nextDouble();
        area = pizzaLength * pizzaWidth;
    } else if (pizzaShape == 2) {
        System.out.println("What is the Diamiter?");
        pizzaDiamiter = keyboard.nextDouble();
        radiusOfPizza = pizzaDiamiter / 2;
        area = Math.PI * radiusOfPizza * radiusOfPizza;
    }

    // Volume
    System.out.print("What type of dough do you want? (1)Classic Hand Tossed,"
        + " (2)Thin and Crispy, (3)Texas Toast, or (4)Pan. \n(Enter 1,2,3, or 4.)");
    doughType = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (doughType == 1) {
        dough = "Classic Hand Tossed";
        doughVolume = area * .25;
    } else if (doughType == 2) {
        dough = "Thin and Crispy";
        doughVolume = area * .1;
    } else if (doughType == 3) {
        dough = "Texas Toast";
        doughVolume = area * .9;
    } else if (doughType == 4) {
        dough = "Pan";
        doughVolume = area * .5;
    }

    // Toppings
    System.out.print("Enter the number of toppings:");
    numberOfPizzaToppings = keyboard.nextDouble();
    toppings = numberOfPizzaToppings;


    // Base price
    basePrice = area * (PIZZA_SAUCE_AND_CHEESE + PIZZA_TOPPING_PRICE * numberOfPizzaToppings)
            + PIZZA_DOUGH_PRICE * doughVolume;

    // Cheesey crust
    if (doughType == 2) {
        cheesyOutput = " no cheesy crust";
        crustCost = basePrice;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Would you like cheesy crust? (1) for yes (2) for no.");
        cheesyCrustInput = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if (cheesyCrustInput == 1 && pizzaShape == 2) {
            sizeOfPizzaCrust = 2 * Math.PI * (pizzaDiamiter / 2);
            crustCost = (sizeOfPizzaCrust * .02) + basePrice;
            crust = "";
            cheesyOutput = " cheesy crust";
        } else if (cheesyCrustInput == 1 && pizzaShape == 1) {
            sizeOfPizzaCrust = 2 * (pizzaLength + pizzaWidth);
            crustCost = (sizeOfPizzaCrust * .02) + basePrice;
            crust = "";
            cheesyOutput = " cheesy crust";
        } else {
            crust = " NO cheesy crust";
            crustCost = basePrice;
        }
    }

    // how many pizzas
    System.out.print("Enter the number of pizzas being ordered:");
    numberOfPizzas = keyboard.nextDouble();
    pizzasBeforeTax = crustCost * numberOfPizzas;

    // tax
    costOfPizzaWithTax = pizzasBeforeTax * (1 + 0.07);

    // delivery fee
    System.out.print("Would you like delivery? (1) for yes, (2) for no.");
    deliveryWantedInput = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (deliveryWantedInput == 1) {
        deliveryOutput = (int) numberOfPizzas + " pizza delivered";
        if (costOfPizzaWithTax < 10) {
            deliveryCharge = 3;
        } else if (10 < costOfPizzaWithTax && costOfPizzaWithTax < 20) {
            deliveryCharge = 2;
        } else if (20 < costOfPizzaWithTax && costOfPizzaWithTax < 30) {
            deliveryCharge = 1;
        } else if (costOfPizzaWithTax > 30) {
            deliveryCharge = 0;
        }
    } else {
        deliveryOutput = "no delivery";
        deliveryCharge = 0;
    }

    // display total
    total = costOfPizzaWithTax + deliveryCharge;

    if (pizzaShape == 1) {
        System.out.print("User requested: Rectangular, " + (int) pizzaLength + "X" 
           + (int) pizzaWidth + ", " + dough
                + ", " + (int) toppings + " topping(s)," + crust + cheesyOutput + ", " 
           + deliveryOutput + " - Program Output:");
        System.out.println("\nDetails for - Rectangular Pizza (" + pizzaLength + "\" X " 
           + pizzaWidth + "\"):");
        System.out.printf("Area:    %.3f\n", area);
        System.out.printf("Volume:  %.3f\n", doughVolume);
        System.out.printf("Base price:   $%.2f", basePrice);
        System.out.printf("\nWith Cheesy:  $%.2f", crustCost);
        System.out.printf("\nMulti Total:  $%.2f", pizzasBeforeTax);
        System.out.printf("\nWith Tax:     $%.2f", costOfPizzaWithTax);
        System.out.printf("\nAnd Delivery: $%.2f", total);
    }

    else {
        System.out.print("User requested: Circular, " + (int) pizzaDiamiter + "\", " 
           + dough + ", " + (int) toppings + " topping(s)," + crust + cheesyOutput 
           + ", " + deliveryOutput + " - Program Output:");
        System.out.println("\nDetails for - Round Pizza (" + pizzaDiamiter + "\" diameter):");
        System.out.printf("Area:    %.3f\n", area);
        System.out.printf("Volume:  %.3f\n", doughVolume);
        System.out.printf("Base price:   $%.2f", basePrice);
        System.out.printf("\nWith Cheesy:  $%.2f", crustCost);
        System.out.printf("\nMulti Total:  $%.2f", pizzasBeforeTax);
        System.out.printf("\nWith Tax:     $%.2f", costOfPizzaWithTax);
        System.out.printf("\nAnd Delivery: $%.2f", total);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: "i just can not get it to work" Could you be a bit more specific about that part?

Comment: Perhaps include the actual error message in your question.

Comment: Also, you'll need to correct your code:  if(pizzaShape = 1) will always return the same, no matter what value pizzaShape has, you want:  if(pizzaShape == 1). You are assigning the value, not comparing it

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: Hi KoopaMarkley, Please select the tick option for the correct answer you feel. This will help other users as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to scopes:

```
if ( condition ) {
  String topping = "topping";
}

System.out.println(topping);
```

Will not compile. (Your code is a bit more broad, but still)

The problem here is that `topping` is a local variable in the if-block, once the if-block is terminated, the variable doesn't exist anymore.

You need to fix it to something like:

```
String topping = "default";
if ( condition ) {
  topping = "topping";
}
System.out.println(topping);
```

Comment: Also has a `Crust`y problem

Comment: same problem, indeed, only exists within that if or that else block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error free code you need. You just need to create the methods and write your logic in it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pizzas {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

      int pizzaLength = 0;
      int pizzaWidth = 0;
      int pizzaShape;
      double pizzaDiamiter = 0;
      double pizzaToppingPrice = 0.025;
      int numberOfPizzaToppings;
      double pizzaSauceAndCheese = 0.036;
      double pizzaDoughPrice = 0.019;
      char doughType;
      String dough = null;
      int numberOfPizzas;
      double pizzasBeforeTax;
      int cheesyCrustInput;
      int deliveryWantedInput;
      int deliveryCharge = 0;
      double doughVolume = 0;
      double area = 0;
      double crustCost;
      int basePrice;
      int costOfPizzaWithTax;


      //Shape of pizza
      System.out.println("What shape of pizza requested?");
      System.out.println("Enter (1) for Rectange or (2) Round?");
      pizzaShape = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if(pizzaShape == 1){
               System.out.println("What Length?");
               pizzaLength = keyboard.nextInt();
               System.out.println("What Width?");
               pizzaWidth = keyboard.nextInt();
               area = pizzaLength * pizzaWidth;
               }
      else if(pizzaShape == 2){
               System.out.println("What is the Diamiter?");
               pizzaDiamiter = keyboard.nextInt();
               area = Math.PI * (pizzaDiamiter / 2);
               }

      //Volume
      System.out.print("What type of dough do you want? (1)Classic Hand-Tossed, (2)Thin and Crispy, (3)Texas Toast, or (4)Pan. (enter 1,2,3, or 4.");
      doughType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
      String Crust = "";
      String deliveryOutput="";
      if (doughType == 1) {
          dough = "Classic Hand-Tossed";
          doughVolume = area * .25;
          } 
      else if (doughType == 2) {
          dough = "Thin and Crispy";
          doughVolume = area * .1;
          } 
      else if (doughType == 3) {
          dough = "Texas Toast";
          doughVolume = area * .9;
          }
      else if (doughType == 4) {
          dough = "Pan";
          doughVolume = area * .5;
          }  

      //Cheesey crust
      if(doughType == 2){
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("Would you like cheesy crust? (1) for yes (2) for no");
          cheesyCrustInput = keyboard.nextInt();
               if(cheesyCrustInput == 1){
               crustCost = area * .02;
                Crust = "";
               }
               else{
                Crust = "NO";
               }
      }

      //Toppings
      System.out.print("Enter the number of toppings:");
      numberOfPizzaToppings = keyboard.nextInt();
      int toppings;
      if(numberOfPizzaToppings == 0){
          toppings = 0;
         }
      else{
           toppings = numberOfPizzaToppings;
         }

      //Base price
      basePrice = area (pizzaSauceAndCheese + (pizzaToppingPrice * numberOfPizzaToppings) + (pizzaDoughPrice * doughVolume));

      //how many pizzas
       System.out.print("Enter the number of pizzas being ordered:");
       numberOfPizzas = keyboard.nextInt();
       pizzasBeforeTax = basePrice * numberOfPizzas;

      //tax
      costOfPizzaWithTax = pizzasBeforeTax ( 1 + 0.07);

      //delivery fee
      System.out.print("Would you like delivery? (1) for yes, (2) for no.");
      deliveryWantedInput = keyboard.nextInt();
      if(deliveryWantedInput == 1){
          deliveryOutput = numberOfPizzas + "deliverd";
         if(costOfPizzaWithTax < 10){
         deliveryCharge = 3;
         }
         if( 10 < costOfPizzaWithTax && costOfPizzaWithTax < 20 ){
         deliveryCharge = 2;
         }
         if(20 < costOfPizzaWithTax && costOfPizzaWithTax < 30){
         deliveryCharge = 1;
         }
         if(costOfPizzaWithTax > 30){
         deliveryCharge = 0;
         }
      }
      else{
       deliveryOutput = "no delivery";
      }

      //display total
      int total = costOfPizzaWithTax + deliveryCharge;

    //System.out.println("Total Due: $" + df.format(total));

      if(pizzaShape == 1){
      System.out.print("User requested: Rectangular, " + pizzaWidth + "X"
      + pizzaLength + ", " + dough + toppings + "topping(s)" 
                      + Crust + "cheesy crust," + deliveryOutput + " - Program Output:");
      System.out.println("Details for - Rectangular Pizza (" + pizzaWidth + "\" X " + pizzaLength + "\"):");
      System.out.println( "Area:  " + area );
      System.out.println( "Volume:" + doughVolume);
      System.out.println( "Base price:   $" + basePrice);
      System.out.println( "With Cheesy:  $");
      System.out.println( "Multi Total:  $" + pizzasBeforeTax);
      System.out.println( "With Tax:     $" + costOfPizzaWithTax);
      System.out.println( "And Delivery: $" + total);

      }
      else{
      System.out.print("User requested: Circular, " + pizzaDiamiter + "\", " + dough + toppings + "topping(s)" 
                      + Crust + "cheesy crust," + deliveryOutput + " - Program Output:");
      System.out.println( "Area:  " + area );
      System.out.println( "Volume:" + doughVolume);
      System.out.println( "Base price:   $" + basePrice);
      System.out.println( "With Cheesy:  $");
      System.out.println( "Multi Total:  $" + pizzasBeforeTax);
      System.out.println( "With Tax:     $" + costOfPizzaWithTax);
      System.out.println( "And Delivery: $" + total);
      }                   
   }
```

**Methods:**

```
private static int pizzasBeforeTax(double d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private static int area(double d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

**Issues in your code:**
1. You have not initialized the variables you have used.
2. You have declared the variables in `if` and `else` clause. When you are planning to re-use the variables, never initialize them inside as their scope is restricted to the block.
3. Also, you have used the same variable name toppings as String and int .